# ClassCastException in kafka-streams join

Tags: scala, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 2 kafka streams that I want to merge. Each of them is typed, and contains the right data:

```
private val inputOrderStream: KStream[String, OrderCreationRequest] =
    orderCreationRequestBuilder
      .stream[OrderCreationRequestKey, OrderCreationRequest]("order-creation-request-topic")
      .map[String, OrderCreationRequest]((key: OrderCreationRequestKey, orderCreationRequest: OrderCreationRequest) ⇒ new KeyValue(key.id, orderCreationRequest))

private val inputPaymentStream: KStream[String, OrderPayment] =
   orderPaymentBuilder
      .stream[OrderPaymentKey, OrderPayment]("payment-topic")
      .map[String, OrderPayment]((key: OrderPaymentKey, orderPayment: OrderPayment) ⇒ new KeyValue(key.id, orderPayment))
```

When I try to join then by bey, I get a very confusing `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ordercreation.OrderPayment cannot be cast to com.ordercreation.OrderCreationRequest
    at com.ordercreation.streams.Streams$$anon$1.apply(Streams.scala:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream$1.apply(AbstractStream.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamJoinWindow$KStreamJoinWindowProcessor.process(KStreamJoinWindow.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndPunctuate(StreamThread.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:557)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
```

Here's the join code:

```
 private val outputStream: KStream[String, String] =
    inputPaymentStream
      .join[OrderCreationRequest, String](
        inputOrderStream,
        new ValueJoiner[OrderPayment, OrderCreationRequest, String] {
          override def apply(op: OrderPayment, ocr: OrderCreationRequest): String = s"Payed ${op.amountInCents} via ${op.method} on behalf of ${ocr.customerNumber}."
        },
        window,
        Serdes.String(),
        null,
        null)
```

Investigating a bit more (using `AnyRef` instead of `OrderCreationRequest` in the `join` method) I can see that the same value of `OrderPayment` is given to both arguments of `ValueJoiner.apply`. Why is this happening? Am I missing anything?

Note: If I print the contents of the 2 streams I get the expected data so I'm sure the topics don't contains the same data.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace to see where the ClassCastException occurs? I would suspect some serialization type miss match and that you need to specify some Serde explicitly using a different overload for `join` method. About `AnyRef`, I suspect this to be the underlying issue: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#scala-compile-error-no-type-parameter-java-defined-trait-is-invariant-in-type-t

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I have added the stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for adding the stack trace. Could it be an Serde issue? According to you code, you don't specify and Serdes when reading the topics as streams. However, both topics to have different type? So default Serde cannot work for both. Same for the join operator. You specify `null` for thus, default Serde from `StreamsConfig` will be used. If that's the case, I am just wondering why it does not failing earlier... (ie, during deserialization). But maybe your serdes just deserialize garbage without crashing.